# TeX Live download fails

Tags: texlive, installing

I have problems installing TeXlive 2017 to my Ubuntu 16.04.3. First I downloaded the `.zip` from the TeXlive homepage, after I unpacked the `.zip` and created the folder `\usr\local\texlive`.
Then I did `sudo su` followed by `.\install-tl`.

I tried like this 3 times and everytime he stops after some minutes or even after a hour with codes like

```
TLUtils::check_file: removing /tmp/bEv_0Yfd3b/9rZn1FT0Qg/cm-super.tar.xz, checksums differ:
TLUtils::check_file:   TL=c4b76b04fc3abbad9b6d611e8588bfabeb6453e5c7d0696daa7bd7236193991869a9f8d7fc498e78357b8fb304f947db3ea25977d1f381edf43c14830acc769d, arg=8ad0ad8119cff2d8bc6e5eda4a214fed1c28f5c645f815c895c92055c622fc8c46bfec130d49e972e800128c57e7ace3e61c516915afb1284c0fdd5b5005f97b
TLPDB::_install_package: downloading did not succeed
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]
./install-tl: Writing log in current directory: /home/patrick/Downloads/install-tl-20180215/install-tl.log
```

What can I do?

Comment: Where exactly is it downloading from? You might be hitting an unstable repository. If you are the only user, then there is no need to install it as root. I normally create `/opt/texlive` and change it so I'm the owner, and then install there.

Comment: The checksums differ? Where did you download the file? As  I understand, don't download the zip, but the tar.gz, which is much smaller, here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

Comment: I am downloading from [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) and I am sorry, surely I downloaded the `.tar.gz` and not the `.zip`.

Comment: No you are not installing TL17 from www.tug.org, you are downloading the installer from tug.org. The TL data is spread around the world in mirrors, such that all the world does not download from tug.org. When the installer starts running it tells you which mirror repository you are installing from. I may be useful for us to know which mirror it is using.

Comment: It is from http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.

Comment: I 'm using the same system as yours and I also faced this issue. Though it may sound foolish, but I was successful in installing by re-trying the installation for at least 5 times. I think at the sixth attempt, I didn't get the typical `checksums differ` error. I'm still not sure this might work for you, but you could still try out.